# RStudio / git doesn't detect new commits on origin (when local is behind remote/origin)

Tags: git, rstudio, gitlab

When I merge changes on my remote (gitlab), then switch to that branch in R Studio, R Studio doesn't seem to detect the changes to the branch on remote - it tells me that my local branch is up to date with remote (origin), when it certainly isn't.  Doing a pull then acts as expected (pulls down all the commits, fast forwards).  Is this the intended behavior?

Here's my workflow (I have a develop branch and a master branch both locally and on remote, and pushing and pulling works fine):

- Make changes to my script on a 'develop' branch.  Many commitments (in R Studio).  Many pushes of develop branch commits up to origin (via R Studio).
- Close R Studio
- Once everything is working and I'm ready to merge the develop branch to master, I open a merge request in gitlab.
- I accept the merge request in gitlab.
- I open up R Studio, switch from develop to master, and get the following message:

> ```
> "Switched to branch 'master'
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'."
> ```

Is this the desired behavior?  My local repo is NOT up to date with origin!  I would've expected a message noting that origin is ahead.  Doing a pull works fine and as expected.

If this is the expected behavior, how do smart git users keep track of whether other people have pushed to master on origin, and if your local repo is up to date with remote/origin? (does one need to check on gitlab or whatever you're using for a remote repo?)

Thanks in advance, hopefully this is a well-formed question.

Comment: Is this GitLab specific? Does it work on GitHub? If not, remove Gitlab complexity from the equation.

Comment: This is not specific to gitlab or github or R Studio.  It looks like I'm getting tripped up by the wording of the message: "Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'."   It appears that the reality is that my branch is up to date with the LOCAL SNAPSHOT of origin/master.  Which is kind of confusing!  I guess i need to always pull